# MongoDB Connection Trouble

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, tomcat

I was connecting to mongodb in my program and there was no problem before, but I can't figure out what's the reason it gives this exception now, I'm running the project by tomcat.
This is my code, and last line is where the exception pops up:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("log4mongo");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("log");
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.append("timestamp",BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gt", date).get());
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
List<DBObject> myList = cursor.toArray();
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
15-Mar-2017 10:57:07.764 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
15-Mar-2017 10:57:07.765 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors



 15-Mar-2017 10:46:51.616 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [MessageBroker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
    15-Mar-2017 10:46:51.616 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [MessageBroker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
    15-Mar-2017 10:46:51.618 INFO [MessageBroker-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.mongodb.async.AsyncBatchCursor]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.mongodb.async.AsyncBatchCursor]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1293)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1158)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
        at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:510)
        at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:81)
        at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:836)
        at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:823)
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor.initializeCursor(DBCursor.java:870)
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:142)
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor.fillArray(DBCursor.java:909)
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor.toArray(DBCursor.java:654)
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor.toArray(DBCursor.java:642)
        at com.hafizco.MainController.onlineTable(MainController.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    15-Mar-2017 10:46:51.619 INFO [MessageBroker-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1293)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1158)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:119)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Logger.java:765)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.error(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:216)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler.handleError(TaskUtils.java:95)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

They are dependency I've added for mongodb:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is contents of Tomcat catalina log file:

```
15-Mar-2017 10:57:07.765 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.error(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:216)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler.handleError(TaskUtils.java:95)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You can solve this problem after restarting the server, the server iscaching older version of the app.

Comment: No change happens after restarting the server, the same exception. @MaheshwarLigade